# The probability of $n$ balls of $m$ colors

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A bag contains only a black ball. Consider the Operation $A$： A  ball is randomly draw from the bag. If the color is black, put it back with a ball of a new non-black color. Otherwise, put it back with another ball of the same color.

**Q:**
If Operation $A$ is repeated $n$ times. How to find the probability $q_n(m)$ that the number of colors of the ball(black is not counted) in the bag is $m$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $s_n(k)$ denote the number of ways of obtaining a bag with $n$ balls containing $k$ coloured balls.
To obtain a situation where you have $n$ balls (in total) with a range of $k$ different colours then you either picked a coloured ball from a bag with $k$ coloured balls ($n-1$ possible ways) or you picked the black ball from a bag with $k-1$ coloured balls. So $s_n(k)$ satisfies the recurrence
\begin{eqnarray*}
s_n(k)=(n-1)s_{n-1}(k)+s_n(k)
\end{eqnarray*}
This recurrence relation defines the Stirling numbers of the first kind and they are the coefficients of the rising factorial function 
\begin{eqnarray*}
(x)_n=x(x+1) \cdots (x+n-1) =\sum_{k=0}^{n} s_n(k) x^k.
\end{eqnarray*}
The total number of possible bags (containing $n$ balls) is $n!$. So the probablity of having $k$ coloured balls is $s_n(k)/n!$.

Answer (score 0):

This scheme is known as **Hoppe's urn**. You can find a plenty of information on that online. You may also look at Shui Feng's "The Poisson-Dirichlet Distribution and Related Topics" for instance.